# remove components from a JPanel and add them

Tags: java, swing

I have to panels in my `JFrame`.

I have a method which called `newGame()` which creates 5 `Jbutton` and add them to the first `JPanel`, and 5 `Jbutton` and add them to the second `JPanel`.

This is the code of `newGame()` method :

```
private void newGame(){

            for(int i=0; i<names.size(); i++){

                //-----Creating name buttons------//
                nameButton.setPreferredSize(dimButton);
                nameButton.setName(namesIterator.next());

                nameButton.addActionListener(nameButtonActionListener);
                namesPanel.add(nameButton);

                //-----Creating image buttons------//


                JButton imageButton = new JButton("x");
                imageButton.setPreferredSize(dimButton);
                final String key = imagesIterator.next();
                imageButton.setName(key);
                imageButton.setEnabled(false);

                imageButton.addActionListener(imageButtonActionListener);
                imagesPanel.add(imageButton);
            }
}
```

I wrote the code to create the two panels in the class constructor, and then I call the `newGame()` method to populate those panels with buttons.

I have a JMenuItem which called "New Game" I want when I click on this `JMenuItem` to remove all components in the both panels, it mean to remove all buttons I added in the `newGame()` method, so this is the code I tried :

```
newGameMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                imagesPanel.removeAll();
                namesPanel.removeAll();
                newGame();
                imagesPanel.repaint();
                namesPanel.repaint();
            }
        });
```

The problem is when the components are removed, and the `newGame()` method called, I can't see any buttons, and the two panels still empty.

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Use a `CardLayout` instead.  And for better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Comment: Also consider updating existing components in place.